# Null reference on an apparent not null object

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

First here is my code:

I have commented the problem lines

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath +  "/directory.txt");
        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        List<string> alst = new List<string>();
        List<string> nlst = new List<string>();
        TableRow[] row = new TableRow[100];
        TableCell[] cella = new TableCell[100];
        TableCell[] cellb = new TableCell[100];
        while (reader.Peek() > 0)
        {
            alst.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            nlst.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            d++;
        }
        foreach (string line in nlst)
        {
            if (i < d + 1)
            {
                cella[i].Text = nlst[i]; //this line
                cellb[i].Text = alst[i]; //and this line always return a null return a null reference when ran
                i++;
            }
        }
        do
        {
            row[c].Cells.Add(cella[c]);
            row[c].Cells.Add(cellb[c]);
            c++;
        } while (c != cella.Count());
        foreach (TableRow item in row)
        {
            Table1.Rows.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

I have checked and all of the variables involved are not null. I have tried cleaning the solution. I have also tried putting static values in for i (like 0), still nothing.

I have been staring at this thing for at least 2 hours, changing loops, ifs, and other things and can still not figure it out.

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Comment: As a side note, you better use `using` block to properly dispose the `StreamReader` otherwise there's risk of leaving the file locked and even memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TableCell[] cella = new TableCell[100];
TableCell[] cellb = new TableCell[100];
```

This creates an Array but does not initialize its values. So

```
cella[i].Text = nlst[i];
cellb[i].Text = alst[i];
```

fails because `cella[i]` is always `null` and `.Text` does not exist (same applies for `cellb[i]`).

You will have to initialize your array first or generate a new TableCell object in your loop

```
cella[i] = new TableCell { Text = nlst[i] };
cellb[i] = new TableCell { Text = alst[i] };
```

Furthermore:

- Consider using LINQ to handle list operations and
- Try renaming your variables to more meaningful ones. `cellb[i] = new TableCell { Text = alst[i] };` looks like an error to me - `N` goes to cell `A` and `A` goes to cell `B`?
- Use the `using` statement when handling streams (and other `IDisposable` objects). This makes sure the stream is properly disposed - even when errors occur.

```
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath +  "/directory.txt");) 
    {
        // your code her ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `TableCell[] cella = new TableCell[100];` you are creating an array of 100 references to `TableCell`, all of which are `null`. If you try to execute `cella[i].Text = nlst[i];`, `cella[i]` is `null`, so you get an exception when you try to assign `null.Text`.

It sounds like you need a loop to fill in values for all the elements of `cella` and `cellb`.

Comment: Sometimes I feel really stupid... I should have thought of that.  Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You are never instantiating the `TableCell` objects in that array; you are only instantiating the array itself. You need to create `new TableCell()` objects for each entry before you can use their properties.